# Need help validating query parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have multiple methods within my controller that takes in query parameters. How can I validate that I am being passed in valid parameters? For example, for the `index` method, how can I make sure that I am getting an array of `authorIds`.

```
def index
  author_ids_array = params[:authorIds].to_s.split(',')

  posts = Post
    .get_posts_by_user_id(author_ids_array)
    .order(sort_column => sort_direction)

  if posts
    render json: { posts: posts }, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {error: posts.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Or in this `update` method. How can I validate that I am getting a valid postId

```
def update
  post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  
  if post.update!(post_params)
    post_hash = post.as_json
    post_hash.merge!(authorIds: params[:authorIds])
    render json: {post: post_hash}, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {error: post.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

***Update***:

Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord


# Associations
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts, dependent: :destroy

  # Validations
  validates :text, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :popularity, inclusion: { in: 0.0..1.0 }

  def tags
    if super
      super.split(",")
    end
  end

  def tags=(value)
    if value.kind_of? Array
      super value.join(",")
    else
      super value
    end
  end

  def self.get_posts_by_user_id(user_id)
    Post.joins(:user_posts).where(user_posts: { user_id: user_id })
  end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  # Associations
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts, dependent: :destroy

  # Validations
  validates :username, :password, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
end
```

User_post Model:

```
class UserPost < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :post
end
```

[image: Feedback]
[image: parameters expected for update method]

Comment: Could you complement your questions by adding the relevant migration code and the model code?

Comment: I added the models, however, I am trying to validate the query parameters. I added something at the end which will hopefully clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use specific render like below   user this in any method like

```
def index
  return render body: params.inspect
.
.
end
```

user below code

```
return render body: params.inspect
```

so  when you use index it will give you params which is passing

OR you can user below code in your application.html.erb above <%= yield%>

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

Comment: How exactly would this prevent invalid params? I don't really need to know what params I'm getting, I just want to make sure that they are valid, if they are not, throw some error.

Comment: I ma not getting your point ,  why you want to check the params is valid or not,  You can use validations in model i think it will help you with your query,   Rails Model Validation

Comment: I am validating the **query parameters**. Not anything dealing with the model.

Answer (score 0):

After your clarifications, your question remains unclear to me and it is difficult to guess what you're doing. But I understood that you want to ensure that `params[:authorIds]` or anything else is an array.

You can see if a given variable is an array the following way:

```
a = ["1","2"]
if a.is_a?(Array)
  puts "is an array"
end
```

With params: `params[:authorIds].is_a?(Array)`

You can use byebug (before Rails 7) or debugger (for Rails 7) to inspect what a param is. As an example:

```
(ruby@whatever: cluster worker 1: 42779 [MyApp]#42793) params[:ids].class
Array
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I just want to make sure that I am given the correct parameters. I added a screenshot that may clear up what I mean by query parameters.

Comment: Assuming that you want to validate that on your controller, the way I said works.